# iFrame changing a css class in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, google-forms

I need support over a modification of an iFrame object: I need to personalize a Google Form embedded in my website.
The only problem I've got is that inside the iFrame the actual form width (not the iFrame width) is at maximum 640px and it's forced by the class "freebirdFormviewerViewCenteredContent".
Now, being inside the iFrame I can't modify it, but if I undestood correctly I can overwrite it with Javascript. I need to change the width from 640px to 90%.
Does anybody know of how to structurate the javascript or have a working script?

I must admit that I'm not very good with Javascript, so every help will be really much appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If your using **Jquery** Try like below,

```
    $(function(){
    $('#iframe1').on('load', function(){
        $(this).show();
        console.log('load the iframe')
         $(this).contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .my-div2{width:90% !important;}  </style>"));
    });
});
```

**`.my-class`** is form class

**[working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/lAFEWQFmMCIhfjRkgU5Z?p=preview)**

or if you want to write styles in saparate css file then do like below.
Write css in **style.css** file

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
frames['frameName'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

**`frameName`** is iframe name attribute

Comment: Thank you @Sai , please correct if I'm mistaken, it's just to check:

`<iframe id="questionario" src="url of the form" width="100%" height="4000" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Caricamento in corso...</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$('#questionario').load( function() {
    $('#questionario').contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .freebirdFormviewerViewCenteredContent {width:90%;}  </style>"));
});</script>`

Comment: Check the Demo Once at https://plnkr.co/edit/lAFEWQFmMCIhfjRkgU5Z?p=preview

Comment: Write the Jquery code in your file, not inside Iframe tag

Comment: Again, thank you @Sai !
I've tried using both my site and the plnkr.co and unfortunately it's not working...
I created a test form and the iframe is:

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSft7EfaY7iqpiRHPC-P02lRSm9g9jdosg31OmlHeQfzvVx21w/viewform?embedded=true" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Caricamento in corso...</iframe>`...
Maybe it's an issue from Google Form?
I really appreciate your help and I'm sorry if sometime I make noob errors...

Comment: Did you get any errors in console? When i use that google docs url , I got error in console saying that Refused to display 'above url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'. which mean google is not allowing to use its url in IFrame

Comment: here it's the error I got:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at contents (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2:26887)
at Function.map (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2:3613)
at n.fn.init.n.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents] (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2:27001)
at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (file:///URL/questionario.html:11:18)
(continue)

Comment: at HTMLIFrameElement.dispatch (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3:12444)
at HTMLIFrameElement.r.handle (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3:9173)

Comment: Right now I'm looking at Google Script Editor to see if I can manipulate the width from there...